# Seeking three specific config variables

Tags: config, config-overrides

I've been trying to figure out how to set three specific CP settings via my config file and can't find a reference for the necessary variables. Maybe somebody can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to find config variables for the following:

- **Apply rank denial to user-submitted links** (CP > Admin > General
  configuration)
- **Deny Access if No IP Address is Present** (CP > Admin > Security & Privacy > Throttling Prefs)
- **Require Member Account Activation** (CP > Members > Preferences)

With the last one I already know that the variable is `$config['req_mbr_activation']` but I don't know what the various acceptable values are.

Can anyone advise? Thanks.

Comment: One general comment: when looking at config variables for CP settings, you can inspect the actual field (text input, radio button, etc) in the CP, and generally the input's field name is the name of the config variable, and the available values (for radio or selects) are enumerated there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from EllisLab.

Apply rank denial to user-submitted links:

```
$config['redirect_submitted_links'] = 'y';
```

Deny Access if No IP Address is Present:

```
$config['banish_masked_ips'] = 'y';
```

Possible values for `$config['req_mbr_activation']`: none, email, manual

Answer (score 5):

Rick, I poked around and found what I think are the allowable settings for those first two in /system/expressionengine/models/admin_model.php. It looks like 'y/n' are the only allowable values for redirect_submitted_links or banish_masked_ips.

I found the values for req_mbr_activation in /system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/members.php at line 1674 (this is EE 2.5.3 I'm looking at) and they are:

```
'req_mbr_activation'        
    => array('s', 
        array('none' => 'no_activation', 
              'email' => 'email_activation', 
              'manual' => 'manual_activation'
             )
           ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Devot-ee's list of config parameters?](http://devot-ee.com/ee-config-vars) and the archived [wiki page](http://web.archive.org/web/20111231063457/http://expressionengine.com/wiki/EE_2_Config_Overrides)?  I don't see one for rank denial there.  But for the IP one there are a few, including:

```
 [require_ip_for_login] => y
```

Comment: Thanks Lisa. I _have_ seen the Devotee list (I’ve been working through it to find all the variables I could relevant to Mark Huot’s advice on hardening EE security (in his excellent ebook). I hadn't seen that archived wiki page, but I've had a look through that as well now. But I can’t see anything that corresponds to those mystery settings (the first two); the one that you picked out relates, I believe, to **Require IP address and user agent for login** (CP > Admin > Security & Privacy > Security and sessions). However that page does give me at least one value for the last variable ("email").

Comment: Does anyone have any further suggestions for config variables for the first two of those CP settings? @LisaWess helpfully flagged up a couple of lists of variables, but none of them, as far as I can see, relate to those settings. As far as the **Require member account activation** setting goes I am assuming that the three possible/acceptable values are 'none', 'email' and 'manual'. Can anybody confirm that?